# memcached session handler in php.ini

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, memcached

I have installed memcached and the below code in php.ini works:

```
session.save_handler = memcache 
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:11211"
```

but when i try to use the memcached handler.. this is not storing the sessions..

```
session.save_handler = memcached 
session.save_path = "localhost:11211"
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php this page says i should be using the second option...

Answer (score 1):

`memcache` and `memcached` are two different PHP extensions. `memcache` needs the protocol identifier (`tcp://`), whereas `memcached` doesn't.

If `memcached` doesn't work, you maybe haven't installed the required PHP module.